# Как записать в файл и считать символы типа "\n"

Tags: python

Есть словарь {символ: код}, нужно вписать в файл и считать в такой же словарь, однако не понятно как быть с символами типа '\n' '\r'?
Код:

```
code_in = {'\n': '100110', '\t': '0101011', 'a': '0101010'}
code_out = {} 
with open('file.txt','w', encoding='cp866') as f:
    for key,val in code_in.items():
        f.write('{}:{}\n'.format(key,val))


with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='cp866') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        key,val = i.strip().split(':')
        code_out[key] = val
```

[image: Пример]

[image: Содержимое файла]

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код, как вы сейчас читаете и пишете в файл и укажите желаемое поведение?

Comment: непонятно, что именно непонятно. эти символы в данном случае ничем не отличаются от других символов.

Comment: Если вы пишете в текстовый файл построчно, то обычно все языки программирования сами при этом добавляют перевод стоки в конце. А вот если в двоичный файл пишете, то всё вручную добавлять.

Comment: Код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: добавил код и содержимое файла, не понятно как мне считывать символы типа \n чтобы по итогу они сдержались в словаре

Comment: вместо `\r` пишите `\\r` и вместо `\n` пишите `\\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

code_in = {'\n': '100110', '\t': '0101011', 'a': '0101010'}
code_out = {} 

formated = json.dumps(code_in}, sort_keys=True, indent=0) 

#запись 
with open('dict.txt', 'w',  encoding='cp866') as f:
    f.write(formated[2:-2])
print(formated)    

#чтение
with open('dict.txt', 'r',  encoding='cp866') as f:
    file_content = f.read() 
code_out = json.loads('{' + file_content + '}')
print(code_out)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное, именно это и оказалось решением <3

Comment: пожалуйста, рад был помочь